# Possible typo in Just/Weese II

Tags: set-theory

I'm just skimming a few pages about Martin's axiom and I cannot seem to make sense of the following exercise:

[image]
[image]

It seems to me that the exercise is trivial hence I deduce that I am missing something fundamental. Why do I think that the exercise is trivial? In $\langle P(\omega) \setminus \varnothing, \supseteq \rangle$ a set $p$ is stronger than a set $q$ iff $p \supseteq q$. In partial order notation, $p \leq q$. Compatible would mean any two elements have a lower bound. Then it seems to me that for any collection of sets their union is a lower bound. Or better even, $\omega$ is a minimum.

Then I thought maybe it should have been $\langle P(\omega) \setminus \varnothing, \subseteq \rangle$. But then the exercise is still fairly easy (even though it's rated non-easy): Let $B = \{ \omega \setminus \{1,2\}, \{0,1\}, \{1,3\}\}$.

What am I missing? Or: what else could the authors have intended? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is in the footnote marked as $^2$?

Comment: Thanks. Second follow up, do J/W force "up" or "down"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think I stated this information explicitly in my first paragraph.

Comment: You'd think that, but no. It seems that they force "down".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Request for clarification: isn't the question "force up or down" the same as asking whether "$p \le q$ stands for "$p$ is stronger than $q$" or for "$p$ is weaker than $q$""?

Comment: Note that J/W probably also mean $\mathcal{P} ( \omega ) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$ where they write $\mathcal{P} ( \omega )  \setminus \emptyset$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I tacitly assumed that : )

Comment: Yes, it means that, but I can't tell whether or not you interpret it that way, or they have defined it that way. I know I had some problems like that when I was learning about forcing for the first time (switching between Shelah, Jech and Kunen).

Comment: From my first paragraph: "...a set $p$ is stronger than a set $q$ iff $p \supseteq q$. In partial order notation, $p \leq q$...." .

Comment: From my previous comment "I can't tell whether or not you interpret it that way, or they have defined it that way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $\mathcal{P} ( \omega )$ (and all of its subsets) is centred under both relations $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$.  In order for a subset $B \subseteq \mathcal{P} ( \omega ) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$ to be not centred in the poset $\mathcal{P} ( \omega ) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$ under one of these relations there must be a finite $F \subseteq B$ whose only "lower bound" (using the definition from the footnote) in $\mathcal{P} ( \omega )$ is $\emptyset$.

- We show that the relation $\supseteq$ does not have this property.  If $F \subseteq \mathcal{P} ( \omega ) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$ is nonempty and finite, then any $\supseteq$-lower bound $b$ of $F$ in $\mathcal{P} ( \omega )$ is also nonempty (since this means $a \subseteq b$ for all $a \in F$), and thus exists in $\mathcal{P} ( \omega ) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$.

Therefore the relation in question must be $\subseteq$.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion : )

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, I believe there are quite a few typos like this in J-W II.  ***Be warned!!***

Comment: They will keep me awake : )